# Are local minima and maxima differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis

\begin{align}
\ f:\mathbb{R}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{R}
\end{align}

According to [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_at_Maximum_or_Minimum) proof, if we suppose that a derivative of a real function at point ${\xi}$ of the form $f'({\xi})>0$, then it can't be an extremum because there always will another points nearby having greater and lesser values. The same situation happens if we suppose that $f'({\xi})<0$. According to the link, since the only option left is $f'({\xi})=0$, this means that if a point ${\xi}$ is an extremum, than its derivative must be equal to zero.

However, the last part of the proof (that which shows that if ${\xi}$ is a minimum or maximum, then $f'({\xi})=0$) was made on an assumption that extrema MUST have some derivative.

What's the proof that this is the case? Why isn't it possible that even if the rest of the function is differentiable, local minima and maxima are not?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking if $f$ needs to be differentiable at a point that extremises the function?

Comment: I'm asking whether it even can be differentiable at an extremum.

Comment: Yes, it can. Take $f(x)=x^2$, with local (actually global) minimum at $x=0$.

Comment: Of course it can. $f(x) = x^2$ has a minimum at $x=0$.

Comment: More to the point, the question asked, as stated, is about the proof of a theorem, and says "Why isn't it possible that even if the rest of the function is differentiable, local minima and maxima are not?" (and the answer is: it cannot, since that is ruled out by the hypothesis of the theorem that $f$ be differentiable) The subsequent comments seem to be about the **statement** of that theorem, questioning the validity of the statement; roughly speaking, "can a function satisfying the hypothesis of the theorem even exist?"

Comment: If that's indeed the case, you may want to rephrase your question -- as of now, it is **not** what it asks.

Comment: It is really not clear what you are asking. You don't prove assumptions.

Answer (score 4):

The statement you link is as follows:

> Let $f$ be a real function which is differentiable on the open interval $\left({a \,.\,.\, b}\right)$.
>   Let $f$ have a local minimum or local maximum at $\xi \in \left({a \,.\,.\, b}\right)$.
>   Then $f' \left({\xi}\right) = 0$.

In particular, $f$ is **assumed** to be differentiable at $\xi$.

**Edit:** If $f$ is not assumed to be differentiable, the whole statement (and proof) fails to apply, and may not even make sense.

Comment: I still don't know why this can be assumed though. I want to know the reason why saying "differentiable extremum" isn't nonsense.

Comment: @Qwedfsf: the theorem says "if $f$ is differentiable at every point in $(a,b)$, including in particular $\xi$, and $\xi$ is an extremum, then $f^\prime(\xi)=0$." This is one of the hypotheses of the theorem: it doesn't need to be justified, because of that. It is like saying "If $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $x^2 \geq 0$." Of course, this may not apply to $x\in\mathbb{C}$, or $x$ being an exotic object like a matrix; but you don't need to consider these cases, since you are only required to show the conclusion for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Qwedfsf think of it this way: if you know for a fact, that you're dealing with a differentiable function, then this is a nice tool to check for local minima/maxima. If you're not dealing with a differentiable function, then you have to think of something else.

Comment: It still doesn't really answer my question. This proof would work if whole function was differentiable. But I want to know why such functions are possible at all. There are objects which certainly don't exist, such as $\frac{x}{0}:x∈\mathbb{R}$. Why isn't "differentiable function" one of such objects?

Comment: @Qwedfsf: I really don't understand what you mean. i'm now assuming your question isn't about the proof of the theorem you link, but actually about the statement itself... is that right? If so, is it "why do they exist functions that are differentiable on a whole interval"? Or "Do they exist functions that are not differentiable, yet have local extrema"?

Answer (score 3):

As Clement C. pointed out in his answer, the proof *assumes* that $f$ is differentiable everywhere on $(a,b)$ (so, in particular, at any local extremum in that interval).

We *cannot* remove this assumption.  To see why, just look at the function
$$f(x) = |x|$$

The function $f$ has a local (in fact, global) minima at $x=0$, but fails to be differentiable at $0$.